# Percorrer string com PHP

Tags: php

Preciso percorrer um string e dentro deste string virá tags de `imagens` preciso selecionar o primeiro.
Estou utilizando o `strstr()` porém não está funcionando.

```
$img = strstr($texto, '%img');
echo $img;
```

Como devo fazer para ter o objetivo correto ?

> O motivo para utilização desta pergunta é porque estou salvando um postagem onde dou opção de salvar com imagem juntamente, mas preciso fazer um preview desta postagem onde faz um thumbnail com a imagem. Por isso preciso percorrer todo esta string para que eu identifique qual imagem relaciona com aquele postagem para assim ir a pasta e identificar para montar a thumbnail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes utilizar uma expressões regulares!

Para lidar apenas com a primeira imagem, podes fazer uso da função [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$html = 'Muita cena aqui pelo meio e com tags<br><img alt="imagem 1" src="imagem1.jpg"/><br/><img alt="imagem 2" src="imagem2.jpg"/><br/>';

preg_match('@<img.+src="(.*)".*>@Uims', $html, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Ver no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/fptQAq).

---

Se pretenderes lidar com todas as imagens, podes fazer uso da função [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$html = 'Muita cena aqui pelo meio e com tags<br><img alt="imagem 1" src="imagem1.jpg"/><br/><img alt="imagem 2" src="imagem2.jpg"/><br/>';

preg_match_all('/<img [^>]*src=["|\']([^"|\']+)/i', $html, $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $key=>$value) {
    echo PHP_EOL . $value;
}
```

Ver no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/NSEwK2).

Para te limitares à primeira, basta sair do ciclo à primeira:

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $key=>$value) {
    echo PHP_EOL . $value;
    break;
}
```

Ver no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ZriMRh).

Comment: o que faz este PHP_EOL.$value ?

Comment: [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol) é para abrir nova linha de forma correta na plataforma em uso (End Of Line), em combinação com o `echo` permite ver o _output_ em multiplas linhas... sem ele teriamos `imagem1.jpgimagem2.jpg` ;)

Comment: Ual kkkkk obrigado pela resposta completíssima !

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde.

Segundo entendi, pretendes ir buscar a primeira imagem correcto? Fiquei foi na duvida se querias o source da imagem ou a tag completa... pelo que fiz o seguinte.

```
<?php

$str = '<im src="urlexemplo/imagem1.png"/><img src="urlexemplo/imagem2.png"/>';

preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)[^>]+>/i', $str, $matchesSRC);

var_dump($matchesSRC);
```

Ou podes ver o funcionamento, [aqui](https://ideone.com/sFV5iM).

Coloquei a imagem 1 com erro para veres o funcionamento do código.

Para ires buscar o SRC da imagem fazes `$matchesSRC[1]` e para obteres a tag completa fazes `$matchesSRC[0]`.

Espero que isto te ajude.

Cumps,
Tiago.

Answer (score -3):

```
public static function removerCaracteresEspeciaiss($str){
    $str_saida = "";
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++){
        $num_asc = ord($str[$i]);
        if( ($num_asc>=65 && $num_asc<=90) || ($num_asc>=97 && $num_asc<=122) || ($num_asc>=48 && $num_asc<=57)){
            $str_saida .= $str[$i];
        }
    }
    return $str_saida;
}
```

Comment: Como isso resolve o problema de buscar uma tag de imagem em uma string???